# Is there a method to disentangle multiple lines of data that are intermingled?

Tags: regression, time-series, trend, test-for-trend

I have 3 temperature sensors that record data once a minute. All 3 temperatures have the tuple value (instant, temperature). The problem is, they may come in a random order and thus there's no way to guarantee that a given temperature came from a given sensor.

Here's an image of what graphing the values looks like if you assume that the sensors are the same each time:

[image]

A human can see that there are 3 distinct functions - one flat trendline near 66 degrees, one gently periodical line near 63, and one aggressively periodical hovering in the range between them.

Is there a statistical method I can use to sort the values into the correct lines?

Edit: If I plot this as a scatter plot, the real lines become a lot more noticeable:

[image]

Comment: Geez, are these all measuring temperature at the same place, or different places? If the same, then maybe you're better off not seeing those weird oscillations, and you can just average them together. If they're from different locations, then you have a real problem on your hands because you can't be sure what it is you're measuring even if you do have a way of disentangling them

Comment: In the figure they are connected by colored lines. Where did that come from? Are you assuming it's wrong? (Eg, the red & orange keep switching over, but maybe the truth is there is no switching.)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point, but isn't this *the* use case for k-means? You know you have three classes and that the future temperature for some class will be nearby to previous measurements for that class. The fact that you also have time data probably can be incorporated to make the problem even easier since temp won't swing wildly in 60 seconds... unless someone sets your sensor on fire.

Comment: @rvl they are distinct locations being measured by one machine that cannot distinguish the inputs - inside of a container and outside of it.

Comment: If you try to use k-means with three classes in (time, temperature) space then obviously you won't be able to separate the three processes properly, especially the red and orange.

Answer (score 0):

1) I don't think it is possible because it seems that your statement about human eye being able to separate them is incorrect. E.g. I can separate the points from your red and orange curves in a different and more plausible way by hand as follows:

[image]

My green and magenta curves look far less volatile and far better separated than your red and orange.

2) If you still think you can do it correctly by eyeballing, then the only way out is to quantify that skill somehow.

Comment: I think the point of the OP is exactly that the green and the magenta lines are the correct ones, and he wants to find them. The red and orange lines result from assigned the readings to sensors in a somewhat random manner.

Comment: That proves my point. To me the first assignment made sense, until after I thought about another assignment that also made sense. Besides, there is this blue line that is very unlike the other two. What if in a new sample all three of them start fluctuating like that?